# Set InnerHTML for Bootstrap 3 dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a Bootstrap input to function as a label as well.

I guess:

```html
 <input type="text" id="xPosition" class="form-control" placeholder="">
```

**and using this to set the text:**

```js
 document.getElementById('xPosition').innerHTML="something"
```

just doesn't cut it.

Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `value` property instead of `innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById('xPosition').value ="something"
```